# Django rest framework API View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make an API view for a custom user model, however I get the following error (Method Not Allowed: /api/v1/users/create), also when I access the API through the browser I get none of the custom fields, but instead I get a media type and a content block.

The serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    phone = serializers.IntegerField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

The View:

```
class CreateUser(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        data = serializer.validated_data

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The url:
`path('users/create', CreateUser.as_view()),`

I expect to get the api view with the first_name, last_name, etc fields to create a user

Comment: please show how you're calling the api endpoint